# Environment to nullify the use of label

Tags: amsmath, expl3

Why does the following code, meant to nullify the action of the `label` command, only work if I don't include the `amsmath` package?

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{nolabel}{}{
  \cs_set_eq:NN \label \use_none:n
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
\begin{document}
\begin{nolabel}
\begin{thm}
\begin{equation} \label{a_label}
a = b
\end{equation}
\end{thm}
\end{nolabel}
%
\begin{thm}
\begin{equation} \label{a_label}
b = a
\end{equation}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

If I don't comment the inclusion of `amsmath` both labels show up.

Comment: amsmath redefines \label locally (it parses the environment twice and so has to avoid multiple labels).

Comment: Is there workaround to locally re-redefine `label` inside that environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

amsmath maps the label to \ltx@label, so you would have to nullify this too:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{nolabel}{}{
  \cs_set_eq:NN \label \use_none:n
  \cs_set_eq:cN { ltx@label} \use_none:n
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
\begin{document}
\begin{nolabel}
\begin{thm}
\begin{equation} \label{a_label}
a = b
\end{equation}
\end{thm}
\end{nolabel}
%
\begin{thm}
\begin{equation} \label{a_label}
b = a
\end{equation}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```